# Reverse Engineering or Electronics

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question on Reverse Engineering:
[How was the Zero Flag implemented on Z80 ALU?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8755/how-was-the-zero-flag-implemented-on-z80-alu)

As you can see it is a question about how a specific circuit of a specific processor was implemented. Which logic gates were used to perform a certain task.

The question is basically "how was it implemented", it is not "how does it work".

Some people think it should be asked on [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/), some people think it should be asked on [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).
Which site is more appropriate for my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may not be a *right* answer to your question, but I would personally have put it on the [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

The simple reason being that your question requires knowledge about electrical engineering and you will find more qualified users on that page than on [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). (There are about 6'000 Users on RE, compared to almost 45'000 Users on EE.) EE therefore exposes your question to more users and it is more likely that most RE members are also EE members than the other way around.

My point extends to stack overflow, where you will find countless questions that might belong to the Android or Unix/Linux sites, but people either do not know about them or simply want better exposure of their question.

Ideally, it should be possible for a question to simply be tagged for multiple boards, but unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Adding to this good answer, RE is geared more towards the processes used *to* reverse engineer. This is evident in the top answer there, which describes *how* to find out the answer to your question, rather than a direct answer you might expect from EE.